# How to build android sample sdk add on x86

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to build a sdk addon and saw that android platform has an example under /device/sample. When I try to build the addon it builds it by default for ARM. I would like to build something for x86.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks,
Gentoo

Answer (score 1):

I have tried building it for x86 architecture in 4.1.2.

You can build the x86 addon by changing the sdk.mk (for ARM)  to sdk_x86.mk (for x86) in file
device/sample/products/sample_addon.mk ( 4.1.2 )

```
# This add-on extends the default sdk product.
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/**sdk.mk**)
```

to

```
# This add-on extends the default sdk product.
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/**sdk_x86.mk**)
```